# How to read xml.gz files using javascript ajax request?

Tags: javascript, xml, gzip

I have access to a TV Listing API that serves me the data in the form of a compressed XML.gz file that I want to access using javascript AJAX calls.
Whenever I try making AJAX request to the URL, it prompts me to download the file, rather than giving it's contents.

Is there any solution by which I can access the XML content of the file using javascript alone?

Answer (score 5):

Browsers decompress `gzip` files "transparently" on fly. You don't need to set any request header manually for this, browser will automatically add the `Accept-Encoding` header as appropriate.

---

**Important :** Web server needs to send appropriate response headers for decompression to work, `Content-Encoding:gzip` in this case. You can debug `Content-Encoding` using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

---

You can give a try to this -

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  headers: { "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip" },
  ...
});
```

Comment: The problem is that whenever I make an AJAX request to the URL, it initiates the download file option in the browser.
I need a way to override the download request for the xml.gz file and fetch the data within.

Comment: can you give me url of the xml file ?